# An output sensitive pattern matching algorithm

Tags: algorithm

This is a pattern matching problem asked me during a 3rd step of an interview (I think it might be an output sensitive version of KMP, not sure. couldn't solve the problem either).

As always, we have a text T, but this time it consists of characters from t_1,...,t_2k and P is a pattern from p1,...,pk.

They are both from same alphabet that has symbols from 1,...,k. But not all the symbols need to occur in the text or the pattern.

If we know that no alphabet symbol occurs more than n times in the pattern P, find a O(kn) algorithm to construct a vector C of length k + 1 where C[i] is the number of positions at which P agrees with ti...ti+k−1.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This is much simpler - look at the complexity - O(kn) - this means brute force:

To compute C[i], just iterate simultaneously over the pattern staring at position 0 and over the text starting at position i and count the matches. This is O(k). 
Therefore to compute the whole C it takes n times that, so O(nk).

Answer (score 0):

C[i] is the number of positions at which T[i + j] = P[j], where j is an offset along the pattern. The obvious way to create this is to scan forward repeatedly at each position in the text, matching P[j] with T[i + j], but in fact you need only consider positions in the pattern that you know are matches with the current text character, and you can deal with all the values of C[i] that any particular text position contributes to before you move along the text,

Create a HashMap holding, for each character in P, a list of the positions at which it occurs. For each character in the text, look it up in the HashMap, and increment C[i - j], where positions j are, in turn, the offsets at which that character appears in the pattern.

Comment: Suppose you are at the final character of text ABCDEFGHIJ and the pattern is JQQJQJ. The answer you want to get is 0000101001, from matches like GHIJ/JQQJ, and to get this you need to increment 3 counters, to produce the 1s, when you see the final j. So in this case the final character produces 3 increments. In fact, each character produces at m increments, where m is the number of times it appears in the pattern. We know that no character appears more than n times in the pattern, so the total work is O(kn) - at most n increments for each of k characters.